# add quotes around an element of a list with vim-sandwich

Tags: substitute

I have an array like this `["/api/static/1_lion.wav",/api/static/2_lion.wav]`, I want to add quotes around `/api/static/2_lion.wav`. I have vim-sandwich, and I have a vague feeling I should be able to do this, or have read somewhere about this, but for the life of me I can't figure it out how to do this easily: neither `w` nor `W` is the selection I want, and there is no symmetrical character around it to use that to select inside. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most plug-ins that take text objects usually include a version of their mappings that works in Visual mode. That also includes vim-sandwich. So one option is to use Visual mode to select the region you want to wrap with quotes and then use the `sa` mapping on those.

For example, you can use `f,lvt]` to visually select the `/api/static/2_lion.wav` part that comes after the comma and goes 'til the close bracket, and then use `sa"` to surround that in quotes.

If you'd like a solution that involves plug-ins, then consider [targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) which includes a text object to select an "argument" (as in, function argument) that works perfectly here. The targets.vim text objects also accept a `n` modifier to select the "next" argument. So from the beginning of this line, you can use the `ina` text object to select the second argument. Putting it all together, `saina"` would work with both vim-sandwich and targets.vim installed.

Comment: targets.vim was what I was looking for! It also has targets for lists, like `a,` with like basically all of the separators you would use: `, . ; : + - = ~ _ * # / | \ & $` (actually, I think a bit more than all :D)